# how to use Lithium PHP framework with enumerated list of collections and changing collection in model

Tags: php, mongodb, lithium

I'm looking to use Lithium framework to build my application config interface as I like its minimal approach and the document-store (i.e. Mongodb) centric model.

However, (and I know its not quite released yet), there is little-to-no information, tutorials or examples out there to move you on from the simple blog tutorial.

What I am trying to do now is build an app that will show me the collections I have in Mongodb, and then let me work with which ever collection I choose. I can't seem to figure out:

a) how would I build a model that enumerates the collections - preferably according to my internal naming scheme,

b) how do I break the convention model so I can specify the name of the collection to use?

I think there are two things i'm struggling with to answer these two questions - perhaps a fundamental misunderstanding of how to move a model in MVC beyond the simple collection-model-controller-view examples, and secondly, the actual process of telling the mongo datasource what collection to use.

any pointers or examples, gratefully received.

Chris

**update::**

So I figured out how to set the collection - for reference you can set source in the $_meta array like this:

```
protected $_meta = array(
    'source' => '<<collectionName>>'
);
```

still no idea how to use a Model that will list me all the collections I have in my DB though. Any ideas how to do that from a philosophical and also technological manner?

**further update::**

so I have got a bit further thanks to the comments below. At least I might now be able to re-phrase the question a bit. I can define my model something like this:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use lithium\data\Model;

class Posts extends \lithium\data\Model{

    protected $_meta = array('source' => false);

    public function testcolls(){
        return (self::connection()->sources());
    }
}
?>
```

then in my view I can use:

```
<?php foreach ($post->testcolls() as $coll): ?>
    <h2><?=$coll ?></h2>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

that works - however, what I really want to do is not create a 'testcolls' method in my Model but as Medhi suggested below, I need to override the find method. I can't seem to figure out how to do that and what it would need to return. The docs are not too clear on this.

**final update**

based on the comment below and a bit of experimentation, I came up with the following that works for being able to call find with a collection as a parameter.

model:

```
class Dataqueues extends \lithium\data\Model{

    protected $_meta = array('source' => false);

    public static function find($filter, array $options = array()) {
        if (isset($options['collection'])){
            self::meta('source', $options['collection']);
        }
        return parent::find('all',$options);
    }   
}
```

controller:

```
class DataqueuesController extends \lithium\action\Controller {

    public function index() {
        $dataqueues = Dataqueues::find('all',array('limit'=>20,'collection'=>'W501'));
        return compact('dataqueues');
    }
}
```

getting a model that returns a list of collections was also pretty simple in the end:

```
class Collections extends \lithium\data\Model{

    protected $_meta = array('source' => false);

    public static function find($filter, array $options = array()) {

        return self::connection()->sources();
    }   
}
```

note that the controller won't support options or filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing holds you from having a `Collections` Model, where you set `$_meta['source'] = false` to prevent Lithium from looking for a Collection in your database named collections.

In this model, you can call `YourModel::connection()->sources()` to list all your Mongo Collections.
Docs for sources(): http://li3.me/docs/lithium/data/source/MongoDb::sources(). Basically it calls `listCollections()` on a MongoDB instance http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.listcollections.php

You can override your Model::find() method to return the list of collections, instead the list of documents, or pass the collection as a param `Collections::find('all', array('conditions' => ..., 'collection' => 'foo'))`... or wathever you want :-)

Lithium is designed to don't force that much on you !

Comment: thanks for that - makes a lot of sense -except I can't seem to get it to work :-(  $_meta['source'] = false; seems to raise a T_FUNCTION parse error, and I'm not sure how to phrase the ::connection()->sources(). I tried $colls = $this->connection()->sources(); with the same result: a parse error. Sorry if this is obvious but its all new to me..

Comment: still no closer - I've tried  `class Test extends \lithium\data\Model{ $_meta['source'] = false; Test::connection()->sources(); }`  but I just get T_FUNCTION parse errors on both lines. Obviously still missing something fundamental about how the Model works. Can you provide a simple example?

Comment: $_meta is a protected property of your model. Ping me on IRC to help you

Comment: That would be great  - how when and where suits you best?

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all, Lithium follows the convention over configuration approach.

What this means:

Configuration: 'source' => '<< collectionName >>'

Convention: Name your model and your collection the same thing, the framework handles the rest.
IE: A "People" collection will have a "People" model

**Second**, connect to your database:

Configure your connections.php file in app\bootstrap\connections.php. I know I said convention over configuration, but you still need to let the framework know where the database is and what the login info is. For details look at the  http://li3.me/docs/manual/quickstart. Here is the relevant code:

```
// MongoDB Connection
Connections::add('default', array('type' =>  'MongoDb', 'database' => 'blog', 'host' => 'localhost'));
```

**Third**, get data
Create a model, matching your collection name, and then in your controller, add this line:

```
$model = Models::all();
```

where model is the singular name for what you are storing in your collection, and Models is the name of your model. **That is it**.
If you put a break point after this line, you will see your Models collection. For more information, see http://li3.me/docs/manual/working-with-data/using-models.wiki

**Finally**, to pass it to your view, simply put this line of code at the end of your controller:

```
return compact('model', 'model2', 'model3');
```

where model would be what you just pulled in the third step. The models 2 and 3 that I tacked on is how you would pass any other collections you pulled.

In your view, you would just reference $model to and assume that the relevant fields are there. You don't have to worry about putting getters or setters or anything else like that.
For example: if you want to show the data in $model:

```
foreach ($model as $aModel) {
    echo $aModel;
}
```

See Accessing View Variables in: http://li3.me/docs/manual/handling-http-requests/views.wiki

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - but thats not really addressing the question(s) - In my case I firstly need to enumerate the collections in my database - which doesn't seem to follow the model used by lithium (and other MVC frameworks), and then, depending which collection I choose, I will want to display all the docs in that collection. Obviously, I can't have a Model for each collection as there might be hundreds so I need to change the collection used by the model. I'm looking to understand how situations like these two, that seem to me to break the MVC model are normally handled.